# What is best way to open URL in new tab in IE browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My requirement is to open URL in new tab in IE browser using javascript. Could you please suggest me the best way.
I wrote following code , but it did not open redirectUrl in new tab in IE browser.

window.open(redirectUrl, '_newtab');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.open() works different in each browser. in Chrome, it will open in a new tab, in IE (11) users need to define if it open in a new window or a new tab in settings, basically there is no way to use window.open to force IE to open in a certain way by javascript.